# Не запускается программа из udev rule

Tags: linux, udev

Делаю правило udev: При подключении bletooth гарнитуры запускать google-play-music-desktop-player.
Путь к исполняемому файлу

```
/usr/share/google-play-music-desktop-player/'Google Play Music Desktop Player'
```

Он есть в $PATH посему и простой командой

```
google-play-music-desktop-player
```

или

```
google-play-music-desktop-player %U
```

Должен запускаться(вообще то не должен, а запускается. Проблема не в этом)
Делаю

```
sudo udevadm info -a -p/path/to/device
```

Получаю вывод

```
KERNEL=="input21"(kernel при каждом подключении новый)
SUBSYSTEM=="input"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{name}=="00:18:09:84:91:DF"
ATTR{phys}==""
ATTR{properties}=="0"
ATTR{uniq}==""
```

Ага..делаю правило

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{name}=="00:18:09:84:91:DF", RUN+="sudo -u umd DISPLAY=:0 google-play-music-desktop-player %U"
```

Перезагружаю правила

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger
```

Переподключаю устройство и не получаю  желаемый результат(плеер не запустился).
Пытаюсь запустить по-другому, потому меняю правило

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{name}=="00:18:09:84:91:DF", RUN+="sudo -u umd DISPLAY=:0 /usr/share/google-play-music-desktop-player/'Google Play Music Desktop Player'"
```

Делаю перезапуск правил, переподключаю наушники и...не получаю желаемый результат.
Гуглю.
На форуме убунтоводов советуют проверить правило. Делаю.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{name}=="00:18:09:84:91:DF",  RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo OK >> /tmp/test'"
```

Перезагружаю правила, переподключаю наушники. Вижу в файле /tmp/test строчку "OK".
Смекаю, что дело не правиле а в способе запуска google-play-music-desktop-player.
Делаю скрипт .conct делаю его исполняемым и бесконечно его редактирую и проверяю работу парвила

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{name}=="00:18:09:84:91:DF", RUN+="/home/<user>/.conct"
```

Никаких результатов. Плеер не запускается. Не буду здесь писать какими способами я пытался запустить программу из скрипта, ибо их было уже много и все здесь не упомнить. Никаких результатов.
Что же не так делаю?
Запускать в без `sudo -u <user> DISPLAY=:0` тоже уже пытался.
Для тех кто скажет что мой скрипт кривой - если его запустить в терминале,  он отрабатывает в любом из испробованных вариантов(плеер запускается)

Comment: Напишите вначале одну команду вместо всего, а именно `env`, и сравните с выводом такой же, запущенной из терминала, где всё работает.

Comment: для отладки перенаправь вывод и stderr в файл (что-то вроде: `RUN+="/home/<user>/.conct >/tmp/debug.out 2>&1"`)... и не забудь сделать `chmod +x`... ставлю на то, что sudo ты не настроил (добавил правило в `/etc/sudoers`), чтобы он без пароля запускал твой скрипт от имени пользователя от которого работает удав... и сам способ довольно не колхозный, но назвать что-либо лучше я с ходу не готов, хотя я бы копал в сторону прослушивания dbus-морды удава специальным демоном... может это даже умеют из коробки какие-то DE...

Comment: @Fat-Zer видимо суждено каждый вариант команды вспоминать. Хоть не хотел. sudo -u <user>> DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus google-play-music-desktop-player

Comment: @Fat-Zer что значит настроить sudo?

Comment: @umd, я подразумевал добавить что-то вроде `%<udevuser> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/script` в `/etc/sudoers`, но скорей всего в данном случае это всё же не релевантно: посмотрел — удав и так от `root`'а работает... а в остальном собственно, как отлаживать — смотри выше...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Сделал как ты сказал в про отладку вот результат. Вопросов только прибавилось. Не понимаю, почему из терминала все нормально открвается а из правила не получается `(google-play-music-desktop-player:7511): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:56:06.350: cannot open display:`

Comment: @Fat-Zer Нагуглил еще про запуск от sudo потому попробовал команду `sudo -E program`. Но результат остался тот же.

Comment: @Fat-Zer попробовал `export DISPLAY=:0; exec google-play-music-desktop-player %U` теперь файл debug.out пустой после переподключения гарнитуры. Но программа все равно не запускается. Еще такая команда: export DISPLAY=:0 && google-play-music-desktop-player %U. Если эти команды вбить в терминале, то плеер запускается, но при подключении гарнитуры не запускаются и при таких командах в скрипте файл /tmp/debug.out пустой. То что он пустой вообще хорошо или плохо? это значит что все выполняется без ошибок или что ничего не выполняется?

Comment: если файл пустой, то скорей всего всё отрабатывает или почему-то не работает сам вывод... можешь свой скриптик запускать с `bash -x` — помимо прочего оно явно выдаст все запускаемые команды... хотя программки могут быть так написаны, что при ошибке они ничего не выводят — возможно им стоит добавить ключик `-v` или даже несколько, а также `echo $?` после, чтобы получить их код возврата...

Comment: кстати, `umd` — это тот пользователь, который залогинен в иксах? в противном случае из X'овой консоли стоит выполнить `xhost +local:`.